# Is there a way to use python to automate the creation of VBA macro files?

Tags: python, vba, automation, solidworks

As part of some workflow optimizations, I'd like to map a large number of [Solidworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SolidWorks) functions to hotkeys. The program itself has the capability to assign functions to hotkeys, but it's only a small fraction of the whole command set. The rest can be assigned to hotkeys by a workaround where a Macro is created that runs that function and assigning that Macro to a hotkey.

Macros are created in Solidworks one of two ways:

1. Within Solidworks a series of commands can be recorded and then they are saved as a .swb file. Running that Macro repeats the recorded command(s). (This method is buggy and really hit or miss)
2. A Macro can be created directly by using Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications which Solidworks uses as a Macro editor. The resulting file is again a .swb file and running it executes the Solidworks functions that it calls. This method is the easiest way to create multiple hotkeys because all I need to do is edit one line of the code and I can execute any function that I want.

Here is what that looks like:

```
Dim swApp As Object
Dim Part As Object

Sub main()
Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
swApp.RunCommand swCommands_Leader_Add_Bent, ""
End Sub
```

The above Example Macro, in VB, adds a jog point to the selected leader line. The line below is the one responsible for executing the Solidworks function.

```
swApp.RunCommand swCommands_Leader_Add_Bent, ""
```

For example, changing `swCommands_Leader_Add_Bent` to `swCommands_Select_Midpoint` now makes the code select the midpoint of a line or edge.

Using that method I can create Macros that can run any of Solidworks' three thousand or so commands. The issue is, the process is a little tedious, and doing it for the dozens or hundreds of commands would be time-consuming. I have the list of all SolidWorks functions so ideally, I'd like to feed that list to some python code, the code edit the `swApp.RunCommand` line with a function from the list, and that code output .swb files that are Macros that are ready to be assigned to hotkeys.

Some other comments:

- I'm not exactly sure what kind of file a .swb file is so forgive me if my terminology is off. I know they are not a text file as opening it up in a text editor results in nonsense. They are edited with Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.1. Solidworks calls them SW VBA Macros.
- I am not looking to Run the macros or the VBA code itself from python. I have already gotten that working and it too slow for my needs. I want to use python to generate the VBA files.
- I have searched around and have not been able to find a method that lets python edit, write to, or generate VBA files.
- The solution does not have to be in python, but that is the language that I am most familiar with. I am open to other languages or methods.

In conclusion, I am looking to automate the creation of a large number of SW VBA Macros (*.swb), can y'all provide any guidance or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, the following should work (not tested!!);

You could create a function to substitute any command name into the code that you provided, like this;

```
def macro_code_text(command_name):
    return f"""
Dim swApp As Object
Dim Part As Object

Sub main()
Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
swApp.RunCommand {command_name}, ""
End Sub
"""
```

..And then you could create a list containing all your command names;

```
command_names = ['swCommands_Leader_Add_Bent', 'swCommands_Select_Midpoint']
```

..And then iterate over the list, saving the resulting texts to files with the '.swb' extension;

```
generic_file_name = 'my_solidworks_macro_'

for i, command_name in enumerate(command_names):
    with open(generic_file_name + str(i) + '.swb', 'w+') as file:
        file.write(macro_code_text(command_name))
```

..This should produce a number of files called 'my_solidworks_macro_0', 'my_solidworks_macro_1' etc. each with a different command name from the list you provided.

Comment: Your method generates a *.swb file that is encoded like a text file, ie. if I open it in notepad I can read the text. However, *.swb files generated by Solidworks, and by extension Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications, are not encoded as text files. They are something else and so in this case your method will not work.

Comment: @JoeKissling Well then you need to specify the encoding, there was no mention of that in your question you just showed what the resulting text looks like, how do you suppose I (or anyone else) should be able to help you then???. And also, "y'all" really?.

Comment: In my question, I state that I do not know the encoding of the file (or rather what kind of file it is) other than it is not a text file as when I open the file the result is nonsense. I have provided as much info as I have on the file with the hopes that someone who knows more about software can provide an answer.

Comment: @JoeKissling In that case I don't think that you can do it from Python, you will probably have to implement the code editor inside VBA, see this link; http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx ... found it here; https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/need-to-run-vba-code-from-text-file.297360/